# How do I get the value of the variable instead of the string value of the variable when using *ngFor on an html property in angular?

Tags: angular

In my template variable I am looping over an async variable using the Async Pipe, *ngFor is working because the correct number of form blocks are being created however; when I log the data from inside the form block component using a setTimeout (to make sure the data has populated, it is just giving me the string value of the variable.

TEMPLATE USING FORM-BLOCK

```
    <app-builder collection="Developers">
        <app-form-block
            *ngFor="let developer of (Database.stream$ | async).Locations"
            data="developer"
        ></app-form-block>
    </app-builder>
```

INSIDE FORM BLOCK

```
export class FormBlockComponent {
    @Input('data') data: any;
    constructor(private Database: DatabaseService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(this.data);


   //EXPECTED OUTPUT: {meta: 'bluegreen',location:'Miami'}
  // ACTUAL OUTPUT: 'developer'




        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I tried to use the {{developer}}
 syntax however it seems that angular doesn't like that too much when its being used to pass data to properties, google searches don't turn up much either, its either that simple or that hard lol

TL;DR seems that angular isn't recognizing the value of the developer variable inside of *ngFor and instead is passing the string value 'developer' to the data property of the app-form-block component.

Comment: Instead of using timeout, can you implement `OnChanges` and see what the value is there?  Are you sure the `data` input is actually an object?

Comment: You are passing it as a `string` working as intented. What you want to do is `[data]="developer"` notice the `[ ]` is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `input` property binding syntax, it will default to passing a `string literal` if its not wrapped in `[]`.

To pass the `variable` developer instead of the `string` developer your template should be:

```html
<app-builder collection="Developers">
  <app-form-block
    *ngFor="let developer of (Database.stream$ | async).Locations"
    [data]="developer"
  ></app-form-block>
</app-builder>
```